# Search returns zero results after changing DNS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, alternate-access-mapping

I changed the name of our Sharepoint server from `http://documents` to `http://dms` with the Alternate Access Mappings interface (zone:default). 
Besides that I changed the urls of the Content Source of search to `http://dms`. 
[image: sharepoint search]

The problem is that the crawl log isn't returning any errors, but search is returning zero results (even with: *). How to solve this?

Comment: Did you do Index reset and after a full crawl?

Comment: @martusha yes I did Unfortunately without result.

Comment: Ah. I found it: was related to a search query pointing to the old url.